# How can I design action sequences in pentaho server 5

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I have a web service which uses `pentaho bi server` and few `ktr` files and one `xaction` file

I know spoon and my `ktr` file is running fine as standalone

But I don't know what is xaction and how to use it.

I am using Penatho 5.

I am searching for pentaho design studio but that looks as old as 2010.

I am not sure what they call in new version of pentaho.

how should I edit the xaction file.

Also

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Design Studio is indeed the correct tool - and it has not changed. However all it is is a ui for designing an xml file - so it doesnt really need updating.

Note however that xactions are deprecated, and for virtually every case there is a better way of doing it now. What is your use case?

Comment: I have a report, designed to run by specific param. When I schedule with the report directly, I can only give one param or it is one report at a time. But I want to loop and generate multiple reports, this can be done in xaction, any other approach for the same?